# Summation of a finite sequence

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions, telescopic-series

This question is linked from my previous question: [Summation of a sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158598/summation-of-a-sequence?noredirect=1#comment8612354_4158598)

Given the sequence:

$$
a_n = 0.9^{n-1}a_1(1+d+d^2+...d^{n-1})
$$
and $a_1=100$ , $d= 1.5$

How to form an equation to find:
$$
\sum^5_{n=1}a_n
$$
Please help me.

Comment: Well, I would start by rewriting the geometric series
$$
1+d+d^2 + \ldots + d^{n-1} = \frac{d^n-1}{d-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

So , $$a_n=0.9^{n-1}a_1\frac{(d^n-1)}{d-1}$$  We need to find : $$\sum_{n=1}^{5}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{5}\left(0.9^{n-1}a_1\frac{(d^n-1)}{d-1}\right)=200\sum_{n=1}^{5}0.9^{n-1}\times(1.5^n-1)$$ $$\Rightarrow200\left(\sum_{n=1}^{5}\frac{1.35^n}{0.9}-\sum_{n=1}^{5}0.9^{n-1}\right)=200\left(\frac{10}{9}\times\frac{1.35(1.35^5-1)}{0.35}+\frac{(0.9^5-1)}{0.1}\right)$$

From here you can find , the answer .

Answer (score -1):

What you have written is $$a_n=90\sum^r_{n=1}d^{n-1}$$.

Now taking summation on both sides

$$\sum^5_{r=1}a_n=90\sum^5_{r=1}\sum^r_{n=1}d^{n-1} $$

Hence it is equal to

$\sum^5_{r=1}a_n=90*(d^0+d^0+d^1+d^0+d^1+d^2+d^0+d^1+d^2+d^3+d^0+d^1+d^2+d^3+d^4) $

$\sum^5_{r=1}a_n=90*(5d^0+4d^1+3d^2+2d^3+d^4) $

Now you may substitute values.

Comment: Thanks for responding. However this is not exactly what I was looking for, actually, I am trying to form a formula so that I don't have to substitute the values one by another i.e. when calculating $\sum^{100}_{n=1}a_n$, I don't have to substitute $d$ by 100 times.

Comment: I think this was the way I came across. Lets wait for some another answer

Answer (score -1):

You just have to rewrite some terms, it's not very difficult. Just remember the geometric sum. We first replace
$$\tag{1}
1+d+d^2 +d^3 + \ldots + d^{n-1} = \frac{d^n -1 }{d-1}
$$
so now the sequence is
$$
a_n = 0.9^{n-1} \cdot a_1 \cdot \frac{d^n -1 }{d-1}
$$
Let's replace $0.9$ by $q$ and then make it $q^{n-1} = q^n/q$. Then we have
$$
a_n = \frac{a_1}{q (d-1)} \cdot q^n (d^n -1)
$$
the part $a_1/(q(d-1))$ is a constant, so we can just name it as $C$ and then we have
$$
a_n = C (qd)^n - C q^n 
$$
When we take the sum over this, we can use Equation (1) again:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^N a_n =& C \sum_{n=1}^N (qd)^N - C\sum_{n=1}^n q^n\\
=& C \frac{(qd)^{N+1}-1}{qd -1} - C\frac{q^{N+1}-1}{q-1}
\end{split}
$$
We can now put the value of $C$ back into its place to get the final result,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N a_n = \frac{a_1}{q (d-1)} \frac{(qd)^{N+1}-1}{qd -1} - \frac{a_1}{q (d-1)}\frac{q^{N+1}-1}{q-1}
$$
In your case, you start from $1$ instead of zero, and $N=5$ so you'll have to adjust the equation accordingly.